# Non-interactive Matlab on HPC?

Tags: matlab, hpc

I have a Matlab m-file queuing on HPC, launched using a batch file (non-interactive mode). While is still queuing, is it possible to modify the content of the m-file without the necessity of relaunching the batch file?

Comment: I'm not much of an expert on batch files, but you cannot update an .m-file whilst running, obviously. Does matlab consider queued batch-processes as running?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know. That's my issue

Comment: I would say try it and see! My guess is that nothing is loaded while in queue, so modifying the m-file should work. Be sure to post your conclusion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a general purpose HPC that supports Matlab , then yeah.

The HPC is doing something else and it only knows that there is a batch file that needs to run when it has time. The batch file is generally not executed until the time of running the job.

This is true at least for HPC running SLURM (read [sbatch](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/sbatch.html) documentation)